# jQuery: add multiple data attributes with each click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a click function setup whereby when you click on the `.click` div, it takes the `data-hook` attribute, and add it as a `data-filter` attribute to the `.button` div, this works fine, but after each click it is replacing the `data-filter` attribute with the new one, ideally I want to add a new value to the attribute with each click, separating each value with a comma. 
Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/pSZ2G/ 
HTML

```
<div class="button">THIS</div>
<div class="click" data-hook="one">CLICK</div>
<div class="click" data-hook="two">CLICK</div>
<div class="click" data-hook="three">CLICK</div>
<div class="click" data-hook="four">CLICK</div>
<div class="click" data-hook="five">CLICK</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var thing = $(this).attr("data-hook");
    $('.button').attr('data-filter', thing);
});
```

If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the previous value and can concatinate with new clicked value, something like.

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var thing = $(this).attr("data-hook");
    var earData = $('.button').attr('data-filter');
    if(typeof earData != 'undefined'){
        $('.button').attr('data-filter', earData + ","+thing);
    }else{
        $('.button').attr('data-filter', thing);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSZ2G/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var thing = $(this).attr("data-hook")||'';
    var df = $('.button').attr('data-filter')||'';
    $('.button').attr('data-filter', df+','+thing)
});
```

on a side note.. I hope you don't have any other elements with a `.button` class in it.. if you're looking to update a single target, you should reference by an id attrib instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".click").click(function () {
   var thing = $(this).attr("data-hook");
   var prevValue = $('.button').attr('data-filter');
   if(prevValue){
       $('.button').attr('data-filter', prevValue +','+thing)
   }
   else{
       $('.button').attr('data-filter', thing)
   }
```

});